# ASP.NET User/Role Editor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

Is there a standard object I should use to edit Users and their Roles in ASP.NET?  Or should I role my own?

Comment: Lib is great or I can buy something or open source would be ok too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a couple of custom aspx pages.

Answer (score 2):

This is one is fairly feature rich and well documented...

http://mywsat.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

What about following classes

- [**MembershipUser**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx)
- [**MembershipProvider**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx)

**EDIT:**
The Roles framework’s functionality is exposed via the [**Roles**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.aspx) class, which contains thirteen static methods for performing role-based operations.

[**CreateRole**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.createrole.aspx) and [**DeleteRole**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.deleterole.aspx) methods will do the job.

Reference : [**http://www.asp.net/learn/security/tutorial-09-cs.aspx**](http://www.asp.net/learn/security/tutorial-09-cs.aspx)

Comment: MembershipUser is the underlying User object of the MembershipProvider not an editor.  I'm looking for a MembershipUser editor.

Comment: Thanks I have all that stuff under control, I'm looking for a ASP.NET Control that will edit users and roles.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a custom implementation of the built-in functionality that you can modify to suit your needs you can find one **[here](http://spikes.codeplex.com/releases/view/40655)**

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in web site administration tool that works well locally: http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3569166/Configuring-Your-ASPNET-20-Site.htm.  This shows an IIS administration tool, but I have not used that so I don't know how well it is.  But that again would require logging into the server.

For our app, we built our own because we needed something more robust anyway, at least for the users/roles part.  I haven't seen anything personally.  You could try checking out the codeplex.com site, I remember seeing some things in the past, but never researched/experimented.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard Membership and Role providers framework for the backend.  There are two out-of-the box Membership providers that handle authentication against the DB or Active directory (SqlMembershipProvider and ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider).   There are a couple of out-of-the box Role providers as well (SqlRoleProvider, AuthorizationStoreRoleProvider, and WindowTokenRoleProvider).

For the front-end, the Logon controls are standard and interact well with the Provider framework...but only for login and changing passwords.

To my knowledge however, there are no standard GUI controls or wizards that have out-of-the box functionality for editing and administering users.  You'll have to roll your own pages for that.